# Opening links in a PWA without showing the url?

Tags: javascript, angular, progressive-web-apps

I've found some similar questions but none that address my particular use case, I have a PWA written in Angular that displays a menu with external links. For example I might open the PWA and see a menu with an icon for Stackoverflow, Github and Reddit. When I open these links they open in a knowdown version of the browser I am using and for some users in a seperate browser instance altogether.

Would it be possible to hide the URL bar  at the top of the screen? My goal is to hide the URL from the user if possible. Before I was using an Android app that was just a webview and that worked great but turned out to be impractical for the use case.

A solution that involves whitelisting domains will not work as I do not know which domains will appear on the links menu.

Comment: Could you use an iframe? Also, if you have any code to share for us to look at that would help.

Comment: @segFault ,exactly what you said,you can do that,some sites might set content security policy ,so that you cant use their website in your frame,i also faced the same scenario,i had bunch of sites to show in my pwa i frame,so some  sites loaded,some did not,so its a funny situation though

Comment: I could use an iframe, would that involve routing all of the traffic through my server though? Including downloads videos etc.?

`<div *ngFor="let link of linkOBJ.links">
<a href="{{link.link}}"><img src="{{link.iconURL}}"/>{{ link.name }}</a>
  </div>`

The HTML boils down to this, how would I redirect the link.link within an iframe in such a way?